# Copy only the first file of a folder VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have found out how to copy all the files from a folder to another folder using VBA.

The only thing I can't find is how that I can only move the first three items of a folder.

I'm taking three pictures per item and for every item I create another folder using an excel sheet. So it should move (or copy) three pictures, and then move to the next three and do the same (but with another folder).

the only thing I can't find is how to select only the three first items from a folder.

I use the .copyfile method at the moment.

```
Dim ESN, FromPath, ToPath, LastRow, PN, FileToCopy, MyFile, i, k,     NumberOfFiles As Integer, Module
LastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 NumberOfFiles = InputBox("How many parts do you want to enter?", "# of parts?")

Dim FSO As Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
'Select all files
FileToCopy = "*.*"


ESN = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
ESN = Right(ESN, 6)
For k = NumberOfFiles To 1 Step -1
'path toekennen
Module = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B" & LastRow - k).Value
PN = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("G" & LastRow - k).Value
FromPath = "D:\DCIM\100OLYMP\"
ToPath = "U:\tmo\Checklist Engine Records\LEAP 1A\PHOTOS\" & Module & _
"\" & ESN & "_" & PN & "\"
MyFile = Dir(FromPath & "\*.JPG")

'folder creeeren als deze niet bestaat
If FSO.folderexists(ToPath) = False Then
FSO.createfolder ToPath
End If
    For i = 0 To 2
    FSO.movefile Source:=FromPath & FileToCopy, Destination:=ToPath
    MyFile = Dir
    Next i
Next k`
```

Thanks!
KawaRu.

Comment: You just need a variable counting how many files you've added, perhaps in a for loop

Comment: use dir() function with folder path and file type loop it thrice with an empty dir() at the end of the loop

Comment: @Jbjstam I was thinking the same but I didn't know how to count items that I've moved.

Answer (score 0):

```
myfile=dir("c:\yourpath" & "\*.jpeg")
i=1
for i = 1 to 3
 ' your commands
myfile=Dir
next i
```

this might help you...add this code in your function or sub...

Comment: Hello, I have tried this but he keeps moving all the pictures to the first folder.

Comment: This my path depends on the source folder .....You can use any other  function inside the loop to copy....Except dir() function because it reset the original dir() from the top

Comment: I got this now `FSO.movefile Source:=FromPath & FileToCopy, Destination:=ToPath
followed by myfile=Dir

Comment: is the to path different for each file? also do you manually enter the path there or is it a static variable. if these are not the case how do you dynamically get the topath values?

Comment: I added my code
I change the path automatically via variables if he changes to another cell with other data. It creates the folder and should then put the right data in it.

Comment: I know the path creation goes well, he also starts at the right object but he doesn't jump to the next object after having 3 items past

Comment: "File not found" Although I know the folder exists and there are files in it

Comment: While using dir () remove the \ within the quotes

Comment: Add a break on the line after my file assignment and debug.print myfile and check the filename is correct

Comment: MyFile contains the name of the first image in the folder.

Comment: Then it's not dir function screwing things up.....It must be something else....Check the topath assignment. Check whether it is assigned the new folder path....After every three files are copied.

Comment: I have found the mistake. It did take the first file from my folder but it did not know where the folder was located. 
Therefore I added     `FSO.movefile Source:=Frompath & myfile, Destination:=ToPath`

Now everything works fine & it divides the images across the different folders. 

Thanks!