# How to copy 100 files to a folder based on first and last file name and display in listbox vba

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform, file-copying

Im trying to come up with a piece of script that will allow me to copy 100 files from one folder and create a new folder based on the first file and last file name and then move those 100 files to that folder.
After moving those files, i want it to display the folders in a userform listbox as clickable items.
For example, each item in the listbox will be a folder, if i double click on a folders name it will display all the contents of the file (of each of 100 files) in a sheet i've set up.

I haven't been able to test this code yet, all i've done for the past week was research and rewrite the code over and over until i could understand it properly before adding it to the program. So there's bound to be some or more errors along the way.

What i did notice was the "objFile.CopyFile Folderpath & FCount & "_" & LCount" piece of code that doesnt specify which files could be copied specifically. For example, i want it to start at the first file and start coping the first 100 files, when the code is executed again, it will start at file 101 and copy the next 100 files. If there's way to ensure that it wouldnt keep copying the first 100 files, that would be awesome!

```
Sub Main()
'====CHECK IF THERE'S 100 FILES====

    Dim filename, folderpath, path As String
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim FCount, LCount, FlagCount, IntCount As Integer
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim obj As Object

    FCount = 0                                        ' First File name
    LCount = 0                                        'Last file name
    count = 0                                         'file count
    FlagCount = Sheets("Flag Sheet").Range("A2").Value

    folderpath = "Work\Big Book\"                     '==================Location Of The Book
    path = folderpath & "*.xls"
    filename = Dir(path)

    Do While filename <> ""
        count = count + 1
        filename = Dir(path)
    Loop
If count < 100 Then

        '====CREATE A FOLDER FOR THE FILES====

        If FlagCount <> "" Then                       '====If there is a flag count, it will create a folder based on the last number it was used
            FCount = FlagCount + 1
            LCount = FlagCount + 101
            MkDir folderpath & FCount & "_" & LCount
        Else                                          '=======================else if there isnt one, it will use the first file name to create the folder
            FCount = IntCount + 1
            LCount = IntCount + 100
            MkDir folderpath & FCount & "_" & LCount
        End If


        '====MOVE 100 FILES TO FOLDER====


        For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder(path)
            If FlagCount <> "" Then                   '====================if theres a flag count it will move the files starting after the flag count + 101
                objFile.CopyFile folderpath & FCount & "_" & LCount
                IntCount = FlagCount + 1
                If IntCount = FlagCount + 100 Then Exit For
            Else                                      '======================================else it will just move the first 100 files
                objFile.CopyFile folderpath & FCount & "_" & LCount
                IntCount = IntCount + 1
                If IntCount = IntCount + 100 Then Exit For
            End If
        Next

    End If

Else
    '===Do Nothing===
End If

End Sub

'=====Display Folders In Listbox=====
    '====Display Folder Items In Book====


'Call the function
DisplayFoldersInListBox folderpath & FCount & "_" & LCount, Me.Listbox1

Sub Button_Click()

    For Each File in Folderpath & FCount & "_" & LCount & "\" & Listbox.value
        '[INSERT BIG BOOK CODE]

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub DisplayFoldersInListBox(ByVal strRootFolder As String, ByRef lbxDisplay As MSForms.ListBox)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fsoRoot As Object
    Dim fsoFolder As Object

    'Make sure that root folder contains trailing backslash
    If Right$(strRootFolder, 1) <> "\" Then strRootFolder = strRootFolder & "\"

    'Get reference to the FileSystemObject
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Get the root folder
    Set fsoRoot = fso.GetFolder(strRootFolder)

    'Clear the listbox
    lbxDisplay.Clear

    'Populate the listbox with subfolders of Root
    For Each fsoFolder In fsoRoot.SubFolders
        lbxDisplay.AddItem fsoFolder.Name
    Next fsoFolder

    'Clean up
    Set fsoRoot = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing

End Sub
```

This link: [Copy only the first file of a folder VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249898/copy-only-the-first-file-of-a-folder-vba)
Seems to be the answer for the coping of the files, but im not entirely sure how to add it to my script. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: When answering a question, I generally copy, paste and refactor.  This is tough to do when the subroutine's header is missing.  I edited the OP's code to make it easier work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back to the basics:

### CopyXNumberOfFiles:Sub

```
Sub CopyXNumberOfFiles(SourceFolder As String, TargetFolder As String, Optional MaxNumFiles As Long = 100)
    Dim fso As Object, objFile As Object
    Dim count As Long
    Dim Path As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not Right(SourceFolder, 1) = "\" Then SourceFolder = SourceFolder & "\"
    If Not Right(TargetFolder, 1) = "\" Then TargetFolder = TargetFolder & "\"

    For Each objFile In fso.GetFolder(SourceFolder).Files
        If objFile.Path Like "*.xls?" Then
            Path = TargetFolder & objFile.Name
            If Len(Dir(Path)) = 0 Then
                FileCopy objFile.Path, Path
                count = count + 1
                If count >= MaxNumFiles Then Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

### Usage

> ```
>  CopyXNumberOfFiles "C:\","C:\Data"
> ```

### Addendum

This function will copy the files over and return an array of the new file paths.

```
Function getCopyXNumberOfFiles(SourceFolder As String, TargetFolder As String, Optional MaxNumFiles As Long = 100) As String()
    Dim fso As Object, objFile As Object
    Dim count As Long, n As Long
    Dim Path As String
    Dim data() As String, results() As String
    ReDim data(1 To 2, 1 To MaxNumFiles)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If Not Right(SourceFolder, 1) = "\" Then SourceFolder = SourceFolder & "\"
    If Not Right(TargetFolder, 1) = "\" Then TargetFolder = TargetFolder & "\"

    For Each objFile In fso.GetFolder(SourceFolder).Files
        If objFile.Path Like "*.xls?" Then
            Path = TargetFolder & objFile.Name
            If Len(Dir(Path)) = 0 Then
                FileCopy objFile.Path, Path
                count = count + 1
                data(1, count) = objFile.Path
                data(2, count) = Path
                If count >= MaxNumFiles Then Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ReDim Preserve results(1 To count, 1 To 2)
    For n = 1 To count
        results(n, 1) = data(1, n)
        results(n, 2) = data(2, n)
    Next
    getCopyXNumberOfFiles = results
End Function
```

### Usage

Column 1 has the original paths and column 2 has the new paths.

> ```
> Dim Files() as String, firstFilePath as String, lastFilePath as String
>
> Files = getCopyXNumberOfFiles("C:\", "C:\New Folder\", 100)
> ```

Original Paths

> ```
> firstFilePath  = Files(1, 1)
> lastFilePath  = Files(Ubound(Files), 1)
> ```

New Paths

> ```
> firstFilePath  = Files(1, 2)
> lastFilePath  = Files(Ubound(Files), 2)
> ```

Comment: I missed something when I read your post.  I updated my answer to simply do what you had asked.

Comment: this way i can use a variable in the `For` statement to get the first and last file name and create the folder and then move the files once it reaches 100. Could you explain this part `If Not Right(SourceFolder, 1) = "\" Then SourceFolder = SourceFolder & "\"
    If Not Right(TargetFolder, 1) = "\" Then TargetFolder = TargetFolder & "\"`

Comment: if i store the files in an array, is it possible to sort it out numerically? My files are numbered from 1-1000 and the code keeps starting from "1,10,11,12,13,14..." instead of "1,2,3,4,5,6..." and so on. Could you help me out again?

Comment: @AnthonyCox I updated my answer to return a 2D array of the file names.

Comment: will this put 100 files into an array and sort it out numerically before moving it to the folder?